# Why isn't the button stretched to edges of the screen?

Tags: android

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="qwerqwerqwerqweqwerqqwerqwerqwerqweqwerqwerqwerqwerqwerwerrqwerqwerqwerqwerqwerqwerqweqwerqwerqwerqwerqwerwerrqwerqwerqwerwerqwerqwerqwerwerrqwerqwerqwer"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/true_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="qwerqwerqwerqweqwerqqwerqwerqwerqweqwerqwerqwerqwerqwerwerrqwerqwerqwerqwerqwerqwerqweqwerqwerqwerqwerqwerwerrqwerqwerqwerwerqwerqwerqwerwerrqwerqwerqwer"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Output:

[image]

Why isn't the button stretched to edges of the screen whereas TextView is?

Comment: Good question. When you look at the source code you can see that a `Button` is actually a `TextView` with very minor changes. I also have no idea what causes them to behave differently

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the properties, the default width set for the button is `320dp`, so if you don't mention any width, it will be maxed at `320dp`. If you want to increase it, you need to enter it manually.

[image: Button properties]

For the `TextView`, there is no default width set.

[image: TextView Properties]

Hence, the Button has that view.

If you want to open those properties, you can get them from here:

> select your widget -> Attributes Tab -> All Attributes -> maxWidth

[image: attributes tab]

Comment: He also uses `wrap_content` on the `TextView`. I think the main question is what determines the width of a `Button` when you use `wrap_content`? Because it is not clear how it is decided

Comment: But my `TextView` has only `wrap_content` )

Comment: @Ivo I just updated my answer

Comment: `textsize` has no influence here. Even when you leave that line out it will stretch the `TextView` to full width

Comment: @VanechikSpace read my answer again. you are having textSize in your text view but not in button.

Comment: @Ivo i will check it and will update the answer accordinglt

Comment: @VanechikSpace I have updated my answer. Have a look and Hope it answers the question.

Comment: @Ivo i have updated my anwer

Answer (score 0):

if you want the button stretched to the screen edge you can write

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```